# tint sprite on mobile disables sprite state change with phaser

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

When I apply

```
this.player.tint = 0xcd0937;
```

to tint my sprite red, the sprite behaves as expected on desktop. The sprite changes color and when the sprite moves left or right all of the sprite state changes are recognized and the tint is active. On mobile, the sprite changes to the desired tint color but stays stuck in the sprite state that was active when the tint was applied.

Anyone know how to achieve the expected behavior on mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a known Pixi bug I'm afraid. We're working on a fix for it, but it's likely to not drop for a couple of weeks yet. Please keep an eye on the Pixi / Phaser repos and you should see it resolved by the end of Sept. 2014.

The reason you only notice it on mobile is because it only happens in Canvas mode (which mobile uses), in WebGL the tint is applied correctly to each frame of the animation. In Canvas it doesn't update the tint cache correctly when the animation frame changes.

Comment: You grace me again with your presence.